# How to set horizontal radio button with HTML table and/or CSS?

Tags: java, html, css, web

I wanted to use the horizontal radio button but I am not sure how to achieve it.
Any kind of help is appreciable, following my code:

```
    <div wicket:id="divRadioButton">
    <table id="centeredTable">
            <tr>
            <td class="sixColumnsTable" align="right"><label wicket:id="lbRadioButtonFourMonths"></label> </td> 
            <td class="sixColumnsTable" align="left"><input wicket:id="radioButtonFourMonths" type="hidden"></input></td>
         
         
            <td></td>               
            <td class="sixColumnsTable" align="right"><label wicket:id="lbRadioButtonFreePeriodChoice"></label> </td> 
            <td class="sixColumnsTable" align="left"><input wicket:id="radioButtonFreePeriodChoice" type="hidden"></input></td>

            </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: that is more of a question of the html + css you use to display the radiobutton and not really specific to wicket.

Comment: I have implemented the html code but obviusly is vertical... I use wicket for a lot of reasons, one of this  because is the framework of the project were actually I'm working

Comment: There is nothing about Wicket here. The question is purely HTML+CSS. I've edited the title and the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution with css flexbox property.

```css
#radios {

  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}
```

```html
<div id="radios">
<label>First radio <input type="radio" name="radios" value="r1"></label>
<label>Second radio <input type="radio" name="radios" value="r2"></label>
<label>Third radio <input type="radio" name="radios" value="r3"></label>
<label>Fourth radio <input type="radio" name="radios" value="r4"></label>
</div>
```